# Windows XP loading screen after format, monitor sleeps

Tags: windows-xp, display

My friend brought me over his IBM intellistation with a 512MB Radeon graphics card.  He has a copy of windows 7 he wants on it.  We did a format and tried to install 7, but at the start up screen the monitor would shut off, the rest of the computer would run, but the monitor shut off.

After messing with this for awhile, he decided to put xp pro back on it.  Well, I formatted, installed set up files, and when it rebooted to finish, the windows screen flickered for a sec and then monitor went off.

I have run `fixmbr` and `fixboot` from recovery.  I've reset all the cables.  The video card is in firmly.

I am lost.  What am I missing here?  There is no setting in bios to turn off onboard video.

I have read in several areas, and did the trouble shooting.  I'm not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the PC is still outputting to the on-board graphics card, which is currently not connected to your monitor. If you have a spare VGA cable you can prove this in 5 minutes (if you are in any doubt.)

I had a similar issue last week- the option was not given an obvious name- so look *very* closely at all the BIOS options. It is in there somewhere for sure. Go through every menu systematically, and read absolutely everything.